# determine the big o running time of the method

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, complexity-theory

```
Static void doIt (int n ) {
    int i;      // 1 operations
    int j; ← (2 x n)    // 1 operations
    while loop (j > 0) {    // n operations 
        I; ← n          // (n+1) operations
            while loop ( i>= 1) {   // (n*n) operations
                I;   ← i/2          // sqrt (n) operations
            }
            j; ← j -1           // (n+1) operations
     }
}

Static int myMethod (int n) {
    sum;  ←     // 1 operations
    for i ← 1 to n {    // (n operations)
        sum = sum + doIt(i);    // (n+1) operations
    }
    return 1;   // a 
}
```

Here is my solution for this pseudocode, but not sure if its correct

```
T(n) = 1 + 1 + n + (n+1) + (n*n) + sqrt(n) + 1 + n + (n+1) + a = n^2 + 5n + 5 + sqrt(n)  
big-o complexity = O(n^2)
```

Comment: are `i` and `I` supposed to be the same variable ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a few assumptions. For instance, I'll assume tht `int j; ← (2 x n)` initializes `j` with `2*n`. I wouldn't expect this semicolon there, but I can't continue otherwise.

With that in mind, your solution is incorrect.

```
while loop (j > 0) {    // n operations
```

Since `j` is initialized with `2n` and decreases by one unit at a time, then this will perform `2n + 1` steps, not `n`. The decrement will perform `2n` steps and the verification brings the `+1` into the equation.

Then there's the inner loop:

```
while loop ( i>= 1) {   // (n*n) operations
    I;   ← i/2          // sqrt (n) operations
}
```

Assuming `i` and `I` are the same variable, then the assignment `I <- I/2` will perform not `sqrt(n)`, but up to `log2(n)` steps in each iteration of the outer loop. Therefore the `while` loop will run the product of the external loop by that value, that is, something upper-bounded by `2n × log2(n)`.

If you fix and sum everything, you'll see that `doIt` is O(n logn). The exact value involves the ceiling of `log2(n)` and a few constants.

The other function, `myMethod`, has a for loop:

```
sum = sum + doIt(i);    // (n+1) operations
```

This line will be run `n` times, not `n + 1`. If you don't need the exact function, that is, if you are only looking for the upper-bound in O notation, then this is O(n).

Since you are calling an O(n logn) algorithm O(n) times, this makes your entire algorithm O(n² logn).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's break down this code. We got a couple of functions doing their thing. First off, there's this doIt thing:

```
void doIt(int n) {
int i;          // 1 op
int j = 2 * n;   // 1 op
while (j > 0) {  // n loops
    i = n;       // (n+1) ops
    while (i >= 1) {  // n loops
        i = i / 2;    // sqrt(n) ops
    }
    j = j - 1;    // (n+1) ops
  }
}
```

Now, onto the main deal, the myMethod:

```
int myMethod(int n) {
    int sum = 0;      // 1 op
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  // n loops
        sum = sum + doIt(i);        // (n+1) ops
    }
    return 1;          // 1 op
}
```

Now, let's add all those ops up and simplify the equation. We end up with:

```
T(n) = n^2 + 3n + 3 + n * sqrt(n)
```

Now, in the grand scheme of things, the big boss term here is `n^2`. So, in programmer lingo, we call it `O(n^2)`